# Delegate with parameter passed as a method parameter - how to access the delegate arg?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, delegates

I'm trying to modify a delegate (itself passed as a parameter) to accept an additional parameter. This is the original method signature:

```
public static T GetCacheItem<T>(String key, Func<T> cachePopulate)
```

I've modified it to look like this:

```
public static T GetCacheItem<T>(String key, Func<string, T> cachePopulate)
```

How do I use the new string parameter?  In the method code I can see that `cachePopulate()` is now expecting `string arg`, but what is it? what do I actually pass to `cachePopulate()`as the argument?

**UPDATE:**

In the pursuit of brevity, I probably didn't explain myself very well. Perhaps I should have asked how to *call* the updated version of the method.  Anyway, the comments helped me understand that the additional delegate parameter is actually passed as an additional parameter of the `GetCacheItem` method, like so:

```
public static T GetCacheItem<T>(String key, string newparam, Func<string, T> cachePopulate)
{
    ...
    cachePopulate(newparam);
}
```

I was convinced that just adding it to the delegate method signature should have worked!

Comment: How are we meant to know? Maybe you're just meant to pass in `key`... but basically, we can't really tell the *meaning* just from the *signature*. Surely you need to decide what you want that parameter to mean.

Comment: If *you* added the parameter, presumably *you* know what to pass into it?

Answer (score 2):

I *suspect* you want:

```
public static T GetCacheItem<T>(String key, Func<string, T> cachePopulate)
{
    // TODO: Try to get it from the cache

    // But if not...
    T result = cachePopulate(key);
    // TODO: Cache it
    return result;
}
```

But basically, *you* need to decide the meaning of the input to the delegate.